# Word Office Javascript API Perfomance

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I would like to develop a Word Addinn. With which I can work my way through the paragraphs of a Word document and customize the formatting of the document. I would like to color the vowels of words in red. I have already developed a prototype. However, this is not particularly fast as everything is processed synchronously. I have not found a way to perform the processing asynchronously.

**works**

```js
export async function run() {
  return await Word.run(async (context) => {
    const start = performance.now();

    const paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;
    paragraphs.load("text");

    await context.sync();

    for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.items.length; i++) {
      const paragraph = paragraphs.items[i];
      if (paragraph.text) {
        const wordsRangeCollection = paragraph.getRange().split([" "]);
        wordsRangeCollection.load("$none");
        await wordsRangeCollection.context.sync();

        console.log(wordsRangeCollection.items);
      }
    }

    await context.sync();

    const end = performance.now();
    console.log(`Execution time: ${end - start} ms`);
  });
}
```

**not working**

> FAILURE
> word-web-16.00.js:25 Uncaught (in promise) RichApi.Error

```js
export async function run() {
  return await Word.run(async (context) => {
    const start = performance.now();

    const paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;
    paragraphs.load("text");

    await context.sync();

    await Promise.all(
      paragraphs.items.map(async (paragraph) => {
        if (paragraph.text) {
          const wordsRangeCollection = paragraph.getRange().split([" "]);
          wordsRangeCollection.load("$none");
          await wordsRangeCollection.context.sync();

          console.log(wordsRangeCollection.items);
        }
      })
    );

    await context.sync();

    const end = performance.now();
    console.log(`Execution time: ${end - start} ms`);
  });
}
```

Comment: Are there any requirement to use multiple `context.sync` methods?

Comment: what exactly would be your suggestion to leave out the last one?

Comment: Yes, call the `sync` method when you need to reflect your changes in the document. Every call of `context.sync` is a round trip from the add-in to the Office document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your implementations have a `context.sync` in a loop. (The `map` method is a loop in disguise.) This is a performance killer. Please use the techniques in this article to get the `context.sync` out of the loop: [Avoid using the context.sync method in loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/correlated-objects-pattern).

Comment: The problem without the sync is the `.items` empty and i can not use it

Comment: I'm not telling you to just delete the `context.sync`. It's not that simple. Follow the guidance in the article to update the code that you call **works**.